# "'this' is not available" in debug windows of Android Studio

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, hugo-logging

I get this message in debug windows in Android Studio. This is not a static method, nor is it a class. What does it mean?

[image]

Comment: what happens if you step over once ?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya what do you mean by "use context"

Comment: if I watch getContext(), it results in "this" is not available

Comment: @Blackbelt if I step over, it continue as it should. (not done in thje screenshot, as my code changed, but in many case in this class CameraPreview)

Comment: Maybe the code is not running on the main thread and that's why when you try to watch something related to context/main thread you get the message "'this' is not available"?

Comment: `this` might be not available when you're pointing to static fields, that was my first thought

Comment: @Sherekan do you mean that debugging outside of main thread make this unavailable from debugger point of view ?

Comment: @Anthony Maybe the debugger can only show what is on the thread where the code is running. I'm not sure, just trying to provide another point of view.

Comment: strange thing here that it already knows the answer yellow text said it is equals zero. but debug console still does not know result. i noticed this behaviour some times console takes some time before show answer. is it your case or does it not show answer at all?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think this is an issue related to Reflexion. My project was using Hugo. As soon as I disable it, the bug disappeared.

Issue has been pushed : https://github.com/JakeWharton/hugo/issues/127

Comment: Thanks , I was using Hugo and as soon as Hugo was disabled , the problem was solved

Comment: Here I am not using any Hugo but still getting the same issue, any solution?

Comment: I am also not using Hugo still having problem.

Comment: In my case it happens when the variable is in lambda blocks, I replace with inner anonymous class and it returns normal.

Answer (score 23):

Inside Lambda block we can't evaluate the value of variables. Changing from the lambda expression to normal expression solved my issue

Comment: i'm sorry, this is true when i check debugging between lambda vs normal one. but, should android studio is capable to debug lambda? or is it impossible for google/intelliJ team to develop it from the first place? because i concern when changing lambda to the normal one, the android studio shows warning and suggest to use lambda instead, but it's weird if the lambda itself is not debuggable...

Comment: This might help a bit : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CRzLZH68rRo - Debugging lambda in java. In this video the IDE is intelli-j only

Answer (score 12):

`this` keyword is references to the current object instance, as in the the official Java [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html).

In your case the error message `'this' is not available` means that the debugger cannot access (i.e. does not know) the current object.

Comment: Is there any commun reason for this behavior ?

Comment: I think it's because the class is compiled without debug info for size and performance reasons.

Comment: Are you building in release or debug mode?

Comment: I assume it was in debug mode, otherwise I would not be able to debug at all.

Comment: Sure you can, just you don't see the variables that are optimized out ;)

Comment: Please how can we fix it?

Comment: I tried to reproduce it, but weren't able to yet, is this your own class, or a built in Android one? Or maybe from some library?

Comment: @bendaf it's a compat Fragment

Comment: Check your build variants if all of them says "debug" than maybe the compat library compiles in release mode from some reason, I am not able to Google it now, but I will be back home tomorrow and check if there is a way to compile it in debug mode :/

Comment: @LisaAnne do you use Hugo from JakeWharton ?

Comment: @Anthony yes Antony. Is it because of it that I get the `"this" is not available" ?

Comment: @LisaAnne I pushed an issue. Did you solve somehow ? or just remove Hugo ?

Answer (score 3):

when i change my gradle config,the work for me.
this is error config:

```
     buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        zipAlignEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }

    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        zipAlignEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

and, this is work for me.

```
debug {

        minifyEnabled false
        zipAlignEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
```

Comment: This should be accepted as a right answer, worked for me, now my watch and debug variabes started to re-evaluate again while im debbuging! THX @didikee

Comment: Does not help debugging a lambda in a click or observe handler.

Answer (score 1):

Change'Build Variant' to debug

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the previous `debug` code with this one:

```
  buildTypes {
    debug {
      debuggable true
      minifyEnabled false
      shrinkResources false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
```