# 'this' is not available android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, this

I have this message during the work with the alert dialogs in the debug window: "'this' is not available"

I saw 2 questions similar( [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35816685/this-is-not-available-in-debug-windows-of-android-studio?noredirect=1&lq=1)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35132129/this-is-not-available-in-debug-windows-of-android-studio?noredirect=1&lq=1)) to mine but I do not have Hugo and I could not find the solution.

**My  gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   compile files('libs/androidsvg-1.2.1.jar')
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:24.2.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:24.2.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

**AND**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**AND My AlertDialogBuilder Code, which is fails on string .setMultiChoiceItems**

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddKeyActivity.this, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
            builder.setTitle(R.string.choose_region)
                    .setMultiChoiceItems(regions, regions_chosen, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
@Override 
public void onClick(...) {...}
....

}
```

Actually in the Activity I have one more AlertDialog.Builder, which works perfectly.

Please, can you help me to find the problem.

EDIT: The problem is that in the debug window I see " regions_chosen - 'this' is not available". The alert dialog is not appearing and the activity crashes.

EDIT2: Initialization of arrays:

```
final String[] regions = new String[Regions.getRegions().size()];
Regions.getRegions().toArray(regions);

boolean[] regions_chosen = new boolean[Regions.getRegions().size()];
```

[image: This is what I saw]

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: @KNeerajLal, I updated the question.

Comment: Could you post the logcat?

Comment: show code where you initialize "regions_chosen" and "regions"

Comment: @DEADMC, I updated the question. Regions.getRegions is the static array of 86 string elements

Comment: What does `getRegions()` return, an `ArrayList`?

Comment: @KNeerajLal, yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
String[] regions = new String[Regions.getRegions().size()];
Regions.getRegions().toArray(regions);
```

to,

```
String[] regions = new String[Regions.getRegions().size()];
regions = Regions.getRegions().toArray(regions);
```

You can optimize the above as,

```
String[] regions = Regions.getRegions().toArray(new String[0]);
```

Comment: yeah, totally! but without modificator 'final' for sure.
Thank you very much.