# 'this' is not available in Fragment while debugging

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

i am debugging an Android app,initially debugging variable value is accessible, but when i get response from an api it says 'this' is not awailable. please help.

i tried below link but no luck

[“'this' is not available” in debug windows of Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35816685/this-is-not-available-in-debug-windows-of-android-studio)

here is the code snippet

```
    Error error = errors.getError().get(0);
                        if (request.getItemSearchRequest().getItemPage().equals("1")) {
                            // display the error on screen if it is first page
                            if (error.getCode().equals("AWS.ECommerceService.NoExactMatches")) {
                                // no results found
                                // check if the keyword is ASIN
                                if (ProductCodeValidator.INSTANCE.isValidASIN(keyword)) {
                                    // get the product info using Item Look up for that ASIN
                                    Map<String, String> params = new ArrayMap<>();
                                    params.put("Operation", "ItemLookup");
                                    params.put("ItemId", keyword);
                                    params.put("IdType", ProductCodeType.ASIN.getRealName());
                                    String requestUrl = getSignedUrl(params);
                                    getViewModel().lookUpASIN(requestUrl);
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                            getViewModel().showEmptyView(getString(R.string.notFound)); // error.getMessage()
                        } else {
                            // display the error as toast
                            showToast(error.getMessage());
                        }
```

i am getting 'this' is not available while debugging "keyword" variable

Comment: where do you define this variable ?

Comment: I have defined that variable inside class. Means it is globally accessible through-out the class.

Comment: ok , so where you do assign a value to that variable then ?

Comment: I have a searchview on submit I have assigned value to 'keyword' that is working good. Then I hit an API and observe it's response using livedata (using MVVM) and when there is a specific value in response I need to hit another API using that keyword . But at second time I get that 'this is not available' and that doesn't work from there bro.

Comment: ok cool, just making sure

Comment: Can you add code of `ProductCodeValidator` class?

Comment: yes this is the method written in ProductCodeValidator class                              ` /**
     * check if string is valid ASIn or not
     */
    fun isValidASIN(code: String): Boolean {
        // this matches the total 10 digits or characters which is the length of ASIN
        return code.matches("^[0-9A-Za-z]{10}$".toRegex())
    }`