# Intellij IDEA Debugger Malfunction: 'this' is not available

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

Recently, I have started getting the above issue in the debugger, where the debugger is not able to find the the 'this' i.e. the current object instance in Java (I am working on Java Project).
Although, I am see the initial value of variables in the class under 'ajc$this' but... I can't use evaluate , nor the value of the 'ajc$this' is modified after actual modification of those variables.

Other issues show :

> ((InputBuffer)((CoyoteInputStream)input.input).ib).lock = Cannot find
>   local variable 'input'
>
> ((UnauthorizedException)ex).code = ((UnauthorizedException)ex).code
>
> ((Response)((Request)((RequestFacade)request).request).response).request
>   = 'this' is not available.

Kindly have a look at this, Debugger is very important.

Resources that I found :-

["'this' is not available" in debug windows of Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35132129/this-is-not-available-in-debug-windows-of-android-studio)

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206183909--this-is-not-available-in-debugger-variables-window

[image]

Comment: There is a similar question, but it is for android studio... I am not able to make sense of the answers, you may.. 

Please find the following link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35132129/this-is-not-available-in-debug-windows-of-android-studio?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I found that it is a debugger console issue, after I cross checked with manual printing the values, while simultaneously checking in the debugger console for the same variable. Code wise I could see the changes, but debugger console was not reflecting them.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, IntelliJ set the default java compiler to Ajc.
After changing it to Javac the debugger worked as expected (Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java Compiler -> Use compiler: Javac)